# How can i traslate from scss to css?

Tags: css, sass

I have this code: i've tried traslate with this page: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css but it does not worked, it say me this line is the problem @include transition($transition-fade);

```
.fade {
  @include transition($transition-fade);

  &:not(.show) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.collapse {
  &:not(.show) {
    display: none;
  }
}

.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include transition($transition-collapse);
}
```

how can i traslate from scss to css plain?

Answer (score 1):

The tool can't resolve the include. Therefor you have to do that manually.

1. go to the source of the `transition` include
2. copy the code
3. find and replace all `@include transition($transition-collapse);` with the copied code
4. adjust pasted code to match the variable parameter passed to the mixin e.g. `$transition-collapse` or `$transition-fade`

Comment: where can i get the source code?